# error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value' when i use methods in other class Python

Tags: python, object, flask

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en flask en el que ya tengo al rededor de 50 clases con distintas funcionalidades, y cuando trato de retornar el valor de un metodo en otra clase me sale el error como el siguiente:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value_one'

pero si le quito a las variables el .self por ejemplo renombro la variable **self.value_one** a **value_one** si funciona. el tema es que no se como hacer que al usar el **metodo add** en la clase print_Maths_Operations, me retorne el valor calculado sin tener que modificar todas las variables del código. el ejemplo a continuación representa el fallo en cuestion que tengo en varias clases del proyecto

```
class Maths_Operations():

    def __init__(self):
        self.value_one  = 0
        self.value_two  = 0
        self.total = 0

    def add(self, x,y):
        self.value_one  = x
        self.value_two  = y
        self.total = self.value_one + self.value_two
        return self.total

class print_Maths_Operations():

    print(Maths_Operations.add("",4,8))
```

Answer (score 3):

¿Por qué pasas `""` como primer parámetro a `add()`?

Supongo que es porque no entiendes claramente qué representa `self` y tienes que pasarle algún valor, pero tal como lo tienes, el valor que pasas es una cadena vacía, de modo que cuando dentro de la función intentas `self.value_one` estás en realidad intentando acceder a `"".value_one` y de ahí el error, ya que una cadena no tiene ese atributo.

La razón de `self` es representar al objeto sobre el cual se está intentando la operación. Ese objeto será una *instancia* de la clase `Maths_Operations` en este caso.

Creas una instancia de esa clase mediante la sintaxis:

```
instancia = Maths_Operations()
```

una vez que tienes esa instancia, podrías pensar que ahora ya puedes usar:

```
print(Maths_Operations.add(instancia, 4, 8))
```

y en realidad sí que funcionaría, pues en este caso `self` toma el valor de la `instancia` que le pasas y ya podrías acceder a sus campos `.value_one` o `.value_two`. Pero esa no es la sintaxis habitual para invocar un método que opere sobre la instancia, sino esta otra:

```
print(instancia.add(4, 8))
```

Fíjate que pones primero la variable instancia, y después separado por un punto el método de esa instancia que pretendes invocar. El método en cuestión está definido en la clase, pero se ejecuta sobre la instancia. Cuando usas esta sintaxis *no necesitas pasar* el primer parámetro `self`, ya que Python automáticamente le asigna el objeto que hay a la izquierda del punto.